# Get position rank of specific row using MySQL query

Tags: mysql, ranking

I have 2 tables:

- user
- checked

Each user has to read a book to finish a course. The system keeps track of each line read by the users in the table `checked`. The users are ranked depending on how many lines they've read; the more you read, the better ranked you are.

For example, there are 5 users:

- Andres, 8 lines read (Andres' position should be 1)
- Romina, 7 lines read (Romina's position should be 2)
- John, 5 lines read (John's position should be 3)
- Mona, 5 lines read (Mona's position should be 3)
- Joey, 0 lines read (Joey's position should be 5)

Here's a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42525e/2) with the structure and data. I'm using *John* for this example:

Get all the lines read by John:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS q FROM checked WHERE id_user = 3;
```

Get a list of all the users in the ranked order:

```
SELECT
user.id_user AS id_user,
user.name AS name,
COUNT(checked.id_check) AS q
FROM user
JOIN checked ON checked.id_user = user.id_user
GROUP BY checked.id_user ORDER BY q;
```

The issue is that I still need a way to get the position rank of a specific user, and only that. For the John example, the query should return **3**.

If we're still using John as the example, my initial idea would be to get John's read line count and then count all the users who have a read line count greater than John's, and add 1.

How could I put that into a MySQL (5.6) query? Of courses other alternatives are welcome!

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `RANK()` analytic function:

```
SELECT
    u.id_user AS id_user,
    u.name AS name,
    COUNT(c.id_check) AS q,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(c.id_check) DESC) position
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN checked c
    ON c.id_user = u.id_user
GROUP BY
    u.id_user,
    u.name
ORDER BY
    q;
```

Note that `RANK` requires MySQL version 8 or later.  If you are using an earlier version of MySQL, there are ways to simulate rank, but they are fairly ugly, and if you expect to have a long term need, then consider upgrading.

**Edit:**

One possible workaround for MySQL versions 5.7 and earlier would be to use a correlated subquery to find the rank:

```
SELECT
    id_user,
    name,
    q,
    1 + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
        (SELECT COUNT(c.id_check) cnt FROM user u
         LEFT JOIN checked c ON c.id_user = u.id_user
         GROUP BY c.id_user) t
     WHERE q < t.cnt) AS `rank`
FROM
(
    SELECT
        u.id_user AS id_user,
        u.name AS name,
        COUNT(c.id_check) AS q
    FROM user u
    LEFT JOIN checked c
        ON c.id_user = u.id_user
    GROUP BY
        u.id_user,
        u.name
) t;
```

[image]

Here is a demo for the MySQL 5.7 workaround query:

### Demo

Comment: Thanks for the input, but the server has MySQL 5.6 and they are not gonna be willing to upgrade it.

Comment: @AndresSK After about 20 minutes of work, I managed to come up with a MySQL 5.7 version for your rank query.

Comment: looks awesome! I'm testing your code but I'm still having a little issue. The requirement is to get the ranked position _of a specific user, and only that_. I added `WHERE c.id_user = 3` in the last subquery... would that be enough? For the John example, the query should only return the row that has this data: **[3, John 5, 3]**.

Comment: @AndresSK Nope, that won't work at all.  You would need to subquery the entire second answer, and then restrict to the user.  The reason is that, if you restrict inside to a single user, there would only be one user to rank, with a dummy rank of 1.  Yeah...a bit ugly, but this is the price you pay for non MySQL 8+.

Comment: I see. Of course, for the ranked order of the whole list is much easier to use the 2nd query in the posted question. The requirement is to get the ranked position of _a specific user_ only. Let me see if I can adapt your last query to achieve that... but it looks kind of difficult and ugly for MySQL 5.x hehe

Comment: You're missing the point of my comment above.  You need to _subquery_ my second answer, and then add a `WHERE` clause restricting to the user you want (e.g `WHERE name = 'Andres'`).  The reason for this is that the rank doesn't exist until the second answer finishes, so you have to subquery it.

Comment: I get it. I meant it looks ugly performance-wise for the MySQL 5.x version. If there are 10k users, i'll have to subquery those 10k records to match a specific id_user: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42525e/9

Comment: Exactly.  You could probably work something out using user variables, but it would also be fairly ugly, and not that performant.  If you have a long term need for this, consider upgrading to MySQL 8+ (or any other database which supports analytic functions).